# I add data into list from API server but size of the list is zero why?

Tags: java, android

I am adding data into the list from model class object still it is showing list size is zero:

```
 apiService.getOrdersDateWise(dateFrom,dateTo).enqueue(new Callback<List<OrdersDateWiseModel>>() {
    @Override public void onResponse(Call<List<OrdersDateWiseModel>> call, Response<List<OrdersDateWiseModel>> response) {

    List<OrdersDateWiseModel> ordsList = response.body();
    int ordsListSize = ordsList.size();
    Log.i(TAG, "OrdersListSize 250 : " + ordsListSize);
    if (ordsList.size() != 0) {
        if (fromDateMillisecs <= toDateMillisecs) {
            for (int i = 0;i<ordsList.size();i++){
                String ordDate = ordsList.get(i).getOrder_date();
                String ordNo = ordsList.get(i).getOrder_number();
                String ordValue = ordsList.get(i).getOrder_value();
                String retaId = ordsList.get(i).getRetailer_id();
                String shopName1 = ordsList.get(i).getShop_name();
                String retName1 = ordsList.get(i).getRetailer_name();
                String area1 = ordsList.get(i).getArea();
                String phone1 = ordsList.get(i).getPhone();

                getOrdersList.add(
                  new OrdersDateWiseModel(
                   ordDate,
                   ordNo,
                   ordValue,
                   retaId,
                   shopName1,
                   retName1,
                   area1,
                   phone1
                ));
        }

       ordersDateWiseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I expected output is the size of the list:

> ```
> I/OrdersDateWiseActivity: OrdersListSize 250 : 0
> ```

Comment: add some more code, not enough to solve your question

Comment: did you initialize object of list that you created?

Comment: Add you adapter class and initilizaion

Comment: Please add more code to solve your issue

Comment: Try debugging the project and put a break point on `List<OrdersDateWiseModel> ordsList = response.body();` and see what you get in the `response` object. I'm guess your response.body() is empty. If there is no data in response object that you want, then the issue either from where the data is coming (server error) or you are not using the API in the right way. Try updating your question and explain what API you are using and how and why are you using it. Thanks